# Facebook Like Button with show_faces=1 only showing up to three avatars

Tags: widget, facebook-like

I'm not sure how to debug this. I paste the code from Facebook as it is given to me including the option to show faces of those that like the page.

I've clicked 'Like' using multiple Facebook accounts (more than three) but I only see three faces, never any more than three.

I searched stackoverflow and the facebook support threads and haven't found much mentioning this.

Could this be a URL scoping issue? The URL for the Like Button is for page other than the one it is on.

If someone could simply recommend how to begin debugging this, I would be very grateful.

I have tried both the iframe embed and the fbml version with the same end result.

http://extremelypublic.com/of/privacy#exposure

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen when there aren't very many Likes (less than 300-500)?